# Trouble initializing Vault

Tags: kubernetes-helm, consul, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to initialize Vault on Kubernetes deployed through Helm in HA mode with TLS and Consul as the backend on EKS.

```
Helm 3.0.2
Kubernetes 1.17
Vault 1.5.4
Vault Helm Chart Version 0.8.0
Consul 1.8.4
Consul Helm Chart Version 0.25.0
```

The cluster is deployed through `eksctl` on AWS EKS.

The error I am seeing

```
helm install -f values.yaml hashicorp/vault
kubectl exec -it vault-o -- vault operator init
Error initializing: Put "https://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/init": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8200: connect: connection refused
```

My values.yaml

```
global:
  tlsDisable: false
injector:
  metrics:
    enabled: true
server:
  extraSecretEnvironmentVars:
    - envName: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      secretName: eks-creds
      secretKey: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    - envName: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
      secretName: eks-creds
      secretKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  extraVolumes:
    - type: secret
      name: vault-tls
    - type: secret
      name: eks-creds
  standalone:
    enable: false
  ha:
    enable: true
    config: |
      ui = true
      api_addr = "[::]:8200"
      cluster_addr = "[::]:8201"
      listener "tcp" {
        tls_disable = 0
        tls_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-tls/vault.crt"
        tls_key_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-tls/vault.key"
        tls_client_ca_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-tls/vault.ca"
        address = "[::]:8200"
        cluster_address = "[::]:8201"
      }
      storage "consul" {
        path = "vault"
        address = "HOST_IP:8501"
      }
      disable_mlock = true
      service_registration "kubernetes" {}
ui:
  enabled: true
```

I have tried changing `api_addr`, `cluster_addr`, `address`, and `cluster_address` over to `PID_IP`, `https://127.0.0.1:8200`, `vault.default.svc.cluster.local`, `https://0.0.0.0:8200` and even a few other variants. So many I really haven't kept track. All with the same issue. I exec into the container and check the `VAULT_ADDR` env var. It's always reflected as I set it in the config. Even updated the `VAULT_ADDR` in the container to the vault kubernetes service ClusterIP. So I doubt it is this.

Some outputs in the vault container

```
/ $ env | grep VAULT_ADDR
/ $ VAULT_ADDR=https://127.0.0.1:8200
/ $ env | grep VAULT_CACERT
/ $ export VAULT_CACERT="/vault/userconfig/vault-tls/vault.ca"
/ $ ls -lAh /vault/userconfig/vault-tls/
total 0
drwxr-sr-x    2 root     vault        100 Oct 27 18:21 ..2020_10_27_18_21_40.431431606
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          31 Oct 27 18:21 ..data -> ..2020_10_27_18_21_40.431431606
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          15 Oct 27 18:21 vault.ca -> ..data/vault.ca
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          16 Oct 27 18:21 vault.crt -> ..data/vault.crt
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          16 Oct 27 18:21 vault.key -> ..data/vault.key
```

I've tried checking the open/listening ports inside the container

```
/ $ netstat -tnlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
/ $
```

Which seems strange. But how would any of my value overrides cause this? So I feel like this is somehow intentional with the way it's setup. But maybe not.

```
/ $ wget https://127.0.0.1:8200
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8200 (127.0.0.1:8200)
wget: can't connect to remote host (127.0.0.1): Connection refused
```

And while `kubectl port-forward vault-0 8200`

```
curl -v https://localhost:8200
*   Trying ::1:8200...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8200 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:8200
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:8200
```

Here is some kubernetes output

```
kubectl get pods
vault-0                                          0/1     Running   0          4s
vault-1                                          0/1     Running   0          4s
vault-2                                          0/1     Running   0          4s
vault-agent-injector-7bd76b66dd-8gjf4            1/1     Running   0          4s

kubectl get service
vault                                 ClusterIP   10.100.165.241   <none>        8200/TCP,8201/TCP                                                         2m1s
vault-active                          ClusterIP   10.100.22.197    <none>        8200/TCP,8201/TCP                                                         2m1s
vault-agent-injector-svc              ClusterIP   10.100.93.216    <none>        443/TCP                                                                   2m1s
vault-internal                        ClusterIP   None             <none>        8200/TCP,8201/TCP                                                         2m1s
vault-standby                         ClusterIP   10.100.96.141    <none>        8200/TCP,8201/TCP                                                         2m1s
vault-ui                              ClusterIP   10.100.219.196   <none>        8200/TCP                                                                  2m1s

kubectl logs vault-0

WARNING! Unable to read storage migration status.
2020-10-28T03:31:47.639Z [INFO]  proxy environment: http_proxy= https_proxy= no_proxy=
2020-10-28T03:31:47.640Z [WARN]  storage.consul: appending trailing forward slash to path
2020-10-28T03:31:47.640Z [WARN]  storage migration check error: error="Unexpected response code: 400"
```

```
kubectl describe pod vault-0
Name:         vault-0
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         ip-172-16-3-151.ec2.internal/172.16.3.151
Start Time:   Tue, 27 Oct 2020 20:31:46 -0700
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/instance=vault
              app.kubernetes.io/name=vault
              component=server
              controller-revision-hash=vault-5dd945bc6c
              helm.sh/chart=vault-0.8.0
              statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=vault-0
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/psp: eks.privileged
Status:       Running
IP:           172.16.3.19
IPs:
  IP:           172.16.3.19
Controlled By:  StatefulSet/vault
Containers:
  vault:
    Container ID:  docker://1c70a35dbb2c870d21616e825200bb766fc10ab8076cd70931305f56386891fb
    Image:         vault:1.5.4
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://vault@sha256:121c1eb16a474f5a4c1d92256184dae333ab7284f8c744d4e2754300f84f68f0
    Ports:         8200/TCP, 8201/TCP, 8202/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Command:
      /bin/sh
      -ec
    Args:
      cp /vault/config/extraconfig-from-values.hcl /tmp/storageconfig.hcl;
      [ -n "${HOST_IP}" ] && sed -Ei "s|HOST_IP|${HOST_IP?}|g" /tmp/storageconfig.hcl;
      [ -n "${POD_IP}" ] && sed -Ei "s|POD_IP|${POD_IP?}|g" /tmp/storageconfig.hcl;
      [ -n "${HOSTNAME}" ] && sed -Ei "s|HOSTNAME|${HOSTNAME?}|g" /tmp/storageconfig.hcl;
      [ -n "${API_ADDR}" ] && sed -Ei "s|API_ADDR|${API_ADDR?}|g" /tmp/storageconfig.hcl;
      [ -n "${TRANSIT_ADDR}" ] && sed -Ei "s|TRANSIT_ADDR|${TRANSIT_ADDR?}|g" /tmp/storageconfig.hcl;
      [ -n "${RAFT_ADDR}" ] && sed -Ei "s|RAFT_ADDR|${RAFT_ADDR?}|g" /tmp/storageconfig.hcl;
      /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh vault server -config=/tmp/storageconfig.hcl

    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 27 Oct 2020 20:31:47 -0700
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Readiness:      exec [/bin/sh -ec vault status -tls-skip-verify] delay=5s timeout=3s period=5s #success=1 #failure=2
    Environment:
      HOST_IP:                 (v1:status.hostIP)
      POD_IP:                  (v1:status.podIP)
      VAULT_K8S_POD_NAME:     vault-0 (v1:metadata.name)
      VAULT_K8S_NAMESPACE:    default (v1:metadata.namespace)
      VAULT_ADDR:             https://127.0.0.1:8200
      VAULT_API_ADDR:         https://$(POD_IP):8200
      SKIP_CHOWN:             true
      SKIP_SETCAP:            true
      HOSTNAME:               vault-0 (v1:metadata.name)
      VAULT_CLUSTER_ADDR:     https://$(HOSTNAME).vault-internal:8201
      HOME:                   /home/vault
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:      <set to the key 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID' in secret 'eks-creds'>      Optional: false
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY:  <set to the key 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY' in secret 'eks-creds'>  Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /home/vault from home (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from vault-token-kfmn5 (ro)
      /vault/config from config (rw)
      /vault/userconfig/eks-creds from userconfig-eks-creds (ro)
      /vault/userconfig/vault-tls from userconfig-vault-tls (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  config:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      vault-config
    Optional:  false
  userconfig-vault-tls:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  vault-tls
    Optional:    false
  userconfig-eks-creds:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  eks-creds
    Optional:    false
  home:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  vault-token-kfmn5:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  vault-token-kfmn5
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                  From                                   Message
  ----     ------     ----                 ----                                   -------
  Normal   Scheduled  2m16s                default-scheduler                      Successfully assigned default/vault-0 to ip-172-16-3-151.ec2.internal
  Normal   Pulled     2m15s                kubelet, ip-172-16-3-151.ec2.internal  Container image "vault:1.5.4" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    2m15s                kubelet, ip-172-16-3-151.ec2.internal  Created container vault
  Normal   Started    2m15s                kubelet, ip-172-16-3-151.ec2.internal  Started container vault
  Warning  Unhealthy  21s (x22 over 2m5s)  kubelet, ip-172-16-3-151.ec2.internal  Readiness probe failed: Error checking seal status: Get "https://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/seal-status": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8200: connect: connection refused
```

I port forward to localhost and get a `PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR` error in my browser.

And I always have the same error. I understand why `vault operator init` is complaining. But I don't understand why that port is not allowing connection to it in regards to how vault has been configured. I'm running out of documentation to read and scowering the net for others with a similiar setup haveing the same error. Most of the time when I find others with this issue. They just have to export the `VAULT_ADDR` and it resolves the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: I am in the same boat, but on AKS...  I'll let you know if I lear n anything...

Comment: You have configured vault to use consul as a backend, and it is expecting to find consul on the k8s host. Where is your consul running?

Comment: @lxop I have consul running also on the same k8s cluster.

Comment: And is it definitely available on port 8501 on the host IP?

Comment: Are you using awskms for unsealing vault? Check if your IAM user/role on that pod can get to kms?

Comment: @lxop Yes. `kubectl get service` shows
```consul-consul-dns                     ClusterIP   10.100.105.56    <none>        53/TCP,53/UDP                                                             3d10h
consul-consul-server                  ClusterIP   None             <none>        8501/TCP,8301/TCP,8301/UDP,8302/TCP,8302/UDP,8300/TCP,8600/TCP,8600/UDP   3d10h
consul-consul-ui                      ClusterIP   10.100.228.152   <none>        443/TCP                                                                   3d10h```

Comment: Check the consul logs - consul is returning a 400 error when Vault is trying to set up its storage, it would be good to know what is wrong with the request

Comment: @lxop I have done a `kubectl logs -f consul-consul-server-0` (and every other running server and agent) while I stood up the vault cluster and even when I exec'd in and ran `vault operator init`. And nothing came out of the logs at all. Literally nothing. Maybe there is somewhere else to check logs?

Comment: Could it be that consul server doesn't have an Cluster-IP address? That makes it a headless service right? There is a consul-dns service with a Cluster-IP. Should I be using that one? I wouldn't think so because it only has port 53 UDP exposed.

Comment: Could any of this be due to ACL policies. I tried adjusting the consul helm values.yaml to set `global.acl.manageSystemACLs: true` and get the `consul-bootstrap-acl-token` secret which it creates from turning this on, and then created the vault acl recommended from the official hashicorp documentation, and nada. I even exported the `CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN` env var in vault, and updated the vault storage config with this token. Still same error.